# Magento2 Installation Error

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm trying to install Magento 2 and I am getting an error.
I tried to google it, but found no solution.

This is the error massage:

```
[ERROR] PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(93): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `cu...', Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(517): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `cu...', Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(580): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('INSERT INTO `cu...', Array) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(576): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `cu...', Array) #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(1853): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('customer_group', Array) #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Customer\Setup\InstallData.php(50): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->insertForce('customer_group', Array) #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(867): Magento\Customer\Setup\InstallData->install(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext)) #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(791): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data') #12 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures() #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(342): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #16 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #17 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #18 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(263): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #19 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #20 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #21 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #22 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #23 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(263): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #24 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #25 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\index.php(35): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #26 {main} Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `customer_group` (`customer_group_id`, `customer_group_code`, `tax_class_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:235 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(93): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `cu...', Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(517): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `cu...', Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(580): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('INSERT INTO `cu...', Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(576): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `cu...', Array) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(1853): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('customer_group', Array) #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Customer\Setup\InstallData.php(50): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->insertForce('customer_group', Array) #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(867): Magento\Customer\Setup\InstallData->install(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext)) #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(791): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data') #11 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures() #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(342): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #15 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #16 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #17 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(263): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #18 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #19 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #20 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #21 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #22 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(263): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #23 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #24 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\index.php(35): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #25 {main} Next Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\DuplicateException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `customer_group` (`customer_group_id`, `customer_group_code`, `tax_class_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php:555 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(580): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('INSERT INTO `cu...', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(576): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `cu...', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(1853): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('customer_group', Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Customer\Setup\InstallData.php(50): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->insertForce('customer_group', Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(867): Magento\Customer\Setup\InstallData->install(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext)) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(791): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data') #6 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures() #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(342): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #10 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(263): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #15 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #16 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #17 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(263): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #18 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #19 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\index.php(35): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #20 {main}
```

Comment: drop all your tables and run installation again

Answer (score 2):

This error message happens when your database is not empty. You have to drop/create db before installation.